# Crop any Image before upload it

Tags: media

I am working on Drupal 7 and the requirement is I need to crop the image before it gets stored or uploaded to the location. I tried with [Imagefield Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_crop) , [Manual Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/manualcrop) , [Smart Crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/smartcrop) and [Image javascript crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecrop) modules. What it does it, at first we need to upload the image and the image will be stored in the location/physical location then only the crop button will be enabled and we can manipulate the image. I dont want to upload the original image instead i want to upload only the cropped image. Is it possible to do like this? Have any one tried something like this?

Comment: You can take a look on https://www.drupal.org/project/original_image_style

Comment: Smalution's suggestion seems good, but if you really can't have the image uploaded to the server at all for some reason, and it MUST be cropped before upload, you'll need to do that client-side in Javascript.  I don't know of a drupal solution for this, but here is a more general solution that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728188/cropping-images-in-the-browser-before-the-upload